# How to bypass captcha in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm given a live site to automate a registration form which got a captcha(Selenium java). Is there any way to bypass it?
I tried the following code to tick the captcha
private By chkbox_captcha=By.xpath("//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1zXb.png)");
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_maindiv"]/div[6]/div/div/div/iframe")));
WebElement captcha = driver.findElement(chkbox_captcha);
driver.findElement(chkbox_captcha).click();
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1zXb.png)

Comment: Captcha verification serves to prevent bots to access the web. For testing purposes there should be an environment without captcha verification or some backdoor (f.e. custom http header) available.